# Unity: How to not add references into List with GetComponent()?

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, pass-by-reference, gameobject, cloning

I have a list of components and I want to give it some values like so.

```
public LoadButtonData loadButtonData;

GameObject clone = Instantiate(buttonPrefab, transform);
LoadButtonProperties properties = clone.GetComponent<LoadButtonProperties>();
properties.filePath = filePath;
properties.Date.text = time.ToShortDateString();
properties.Name.text = fileName;
properties.Place.text = DataLoaded.sceneName;
properties.Thumbnail.sprite = newSprite;
loadButtonData.loadButtons.Add(properties);
```

`LoadButtonData` is an object contained within another object with DontDestroyOnLoad() and is used across multiple scenes. However, after switching scenes, this happens:

[image]

I understand that this is because the properties are added into the list as references and upon changing scene, the button clones are destroyed and can't be referenced anymore.

Is there a workaround for this, for me to reuse my values throughout my scenes as actual values and not references? How do I add **copies** of the clone's `LoadButtonProperties` data instead of references to the clone?

Edit: Rephrased the question above for clarification

Edit: This is the LoadButtonProperties class

```
public class LoadButtonProperties : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Path to the json file for loading
    /// </summary>
    public string filePath;

    [Tooltip("Place Date here")]
    public TextMeshProUGUI Date;
    [Tooltip("Place Name here")]
    public TextMeshProUGUI Name;
    [Tooltip("Place Place here")]
    public TextMeshProUGUI Place;
    [Tooltip("Place Thumbnail here")]
    public Image Thumbnail;
}
```

DeepCloning was attempted but I couldn't manage to do it because of the `Image` variable

Comment: Have you looked into additive level loading at all?

Comment: Is it advisable to load multiple levels for a VR app? Just loading 1 takes up close to 1gb of memory

Comment: Loading levels additively is a known approach to avoiding just that! Split your levels up, load the parts you're using now, and unload the parts you're not. You'll see this a lot in AAA games, there's usually something like an elevator to split the level up and and allow for async loading. You can find an example of persistent levels in the Adventure Game tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vi8S2PgMvds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You (realistically) can't

The only way to keep those references "alive" is to prevent those objects from being destroyed in the first place (which isn't viable when dealing with scene changes).

Keeping..."a hold" of the object while it is removed from memory and recreated isn't really possible. You might be able to set up some weird serialization/deserialization step, but you'd have to make your list some kind of UUID that when you change scenes, the objects figure out their UUID and the list queries the scene for objects with that UUID, but...it's going to be messy. And might not even work all the time.

You're better off saying "this data is volatile" and building with that in mind. Just let things expire and recreate (if neccessary) them when the scene changes.

Comment: It seems like I didn't phrase the last sentences of my question right. I want to use the values as cached data and not references

Comment: @Ryolu You can't. When the scene changes and those objects are destroyed, they're gone. If you want to cache their *data*, cache their *data.*

Comment: how should I go about doing that? I tried deep cloning but I can't seem to make it work because of the `Image` variable that I have

Comment: `GameObject != Data`, `Component != Data`. Create a *class you control* that stores the same information and push **that** into your list.

Comment: That very class is in the edit. However, it is a component of the `GameObject` that is to be destroyed

Comment: ...Do not use components. `Component != Data`. Have you forgotten that classes can exist *outside* of the scene hierarchy?

Comment: Actually, I didn't know that at all.. Any useful links to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a tad contradictory since you ask how to keep references between scenes, but then ask how to not keep them between scenes.

As for how to clear them between scenes, you can just reset your list of buttons with a new list. This will let you start from scratch between scenes.

If you want to keep data and objects between scenes you can use serialization and DontDestroyOnLoad

check out this tutorial: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/persistence-saving-and-loading-data for more information about data persistence.

EDIT:
To destroy all the buttons as you change between scenes you can do something along the lines of this:

```
foreach (LoadButtonProperties buttonToDelete in loadButtons) {
    Destroy(buttonToDelete.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't phrase it right. The buttons are specific to the scene and have to be destroyed upon changing scenes. I'm trying to pass the data in as an object and not reference

Comment: see edits. You can access a component's object through the .gameObject property.

Comment: The buttons **are** destroyed. My concern is that if there's any other way to store the information those buttons held without actually retaining the buttons themselves

Comment: I think you need to edit your question to improve clarity. Both answers here are misunderstanding your goals completely.

Comment: I have no idea how else to phrase it, my command of english isn't adequate. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't pretty, but you have to copy/clone all the elements (and if one of them is a list, if you clone the list, it won't be the same but the elements in the list will be references).

You can try using a temporary object that only passes data.

Comment: I tried this, but I was unable to clone the `Thumbnail` as it is an `Image`

Comment: This [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/103760/how-to-instantiate-ui-image-in-unity2d) solves how to instantiate an Image.